# Why doesn't Appsync subscription work for object input parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using AWS `appsync` for graphql communication. I have below schema for subscription:

```
type Subscription {
    requestTransaction(id: ID!): Transaction!
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["transactionResponse"])
}
```

it works fine. The subscription receives events when the `transactionResponse` mutation returns an evnet {id: '123'}. However, if I add a object type to the subscription `requestTransaction` like below code:

```
type Subscription {
    requestTransaction(transaction: TransactionInput!): Transaction!
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["transactionResponse"])
}

input TransactionInput {
    id: ID!
}
```

the subscription doesn't receive any events even if `mutation` response `{transaction: {id: '123'}}` event.

I wonder why `Appsync` doesn't support object input parameter?

Comment: Not sure if you found an answer but I noticed the same thing and ended up using the separate input parameter format instead for the subscription, similar to your first example, then it works.